# How to Compile SSL onto Cygwin for windows?

Tags: random

Below is what showed when i configured.  I included all of the packages in the cygwin installer (it took me forever to tick off all the "skip" boxes)

```
`$ ./configure

Starting hydra auto configuration ...

Checking for openssl (libssl, libcrypto, ssl.h, sha.h)
found
Checking for idn (libidn.so) ... found
Checking for curses (libcurses.so / term.h) ... found, color output enabled
Checking for pcre (libpcre.so, pcre.h) ... found
Checking for Postgres (libpq.so, libpq-fe.h) ... DISABLED - postgres is buggy in Cygwin at the moment
Checking for SVN (libsvn_client-1 libapr-1.so libaprutil-1.so) ... found
Checking for firebird (libfbclient.so) ... NOT found, module firebird disabled
Checking for MYSQL client (libmysqlclient.so, math.h) ... found
Checking for AFP (libafpclient.so) ... NOT found, module Apple Filing Protocol disabled - Apple sucks anyway

Checking for NCP (libncp.so / nwcalls.h) ... NOT found, module NCP disabled
Checking for SAP/R3 (librfc/saprfc.h) ... NOT found, module sapr3 disabled
Checking for libssh (libssh/libssh.h) ... NOT found, module ssh disabled Get it from http://www.libssh.org

Checking for Oracle (libocci.so libclntsh.so / oci.h and libaio.so) ... NOT found, module Oracle disabled
Checking for GUI req's (pkg-config, gtk+-2.0) ... found
Checking for Android specialities ... rindex() found
                                  ... RSA_generate_key() found

Hydra will be installed into .../bin of: /usr/local
  (change this by running ./configure --prefix=path)`
```

When I try to initiate a HTTPS attack, for example `https-form-post`, I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Compiled without SSL support, module not available
```

Comment: Dood, you keep asking admin questions about Cygwin. May I suggest you run Kali in a VM instead? Much less stressful.  VMware Player, Virtualbox, etc are free.

Comment: @DavidHoude this? https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=GSX-200-AUTH-SERVICE-DT&productId=129

Comment: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

Comment: @DavidHoude Thanks David!!  I'm gonna try this.  Any chance you'll be available to help me with whatever issue may arise? maybe we could get eachother's email or skype or something?

Comment: http://webchat.freenode.net/ channel #kali-linux is my best suggestion to you.